# i am projecting the mongodb document itself but one works and the other doesn't

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using mongodb for my .net core web api. And I have 2 models that return to the client:

```
public class Model1
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("data")]
    public InnerModel[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class InnerModel
{
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the service for `Model` I use LINQ in the following way:

```
public (List<Model1> models, int data) Get(string x)
{
    var result = from m in db.GetCollection<Model1>("model1")
                 where m.name == x
                 select m;

    var models = result.Skip(y).Take(y).ToList();
    return (models, z);
}
```

This function works perfectly fine.

In the service for Model2, I use LINQ in a different way:

```
public List<Model2> Get(string x)
{
    var result = from m in db.GetCollection<Model2>("model2")
                 let v = evaluate(m, x)
                 where v > 0
                 orderby v descending
                 select m;
    return result.Skip(y).Take(y).ToList();
}
```

However the 2nd `Get` function gives me an exception of `$project or $group does not support <document>`. I had a look at the other posts but I really don't understand what they mean.

I guess I am projecting the document itself in my first `Get` which just works? Is it because my `Model2` has an embedded object in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as i know, `let` is not supported by the mongodb driver for translation in to a valid mongo query. so you would have to do something like the following.

```cs
var query = (from m in db.GetCollection<Model2>("model2").AsQueryable()
             where m.Data.Any(d => d.Name == x)
             select m)
            .Skip(0)
            .Take(100);

var sorted = from m in query.ToList()
             orderby m.Data.Select(d => d.Name == x).Count() descending
             select m;
```

notice that the sorting is done in memory after retrieving the matching models from the db in a second step.

Comment: Thanks for your code. In your step one, can I still call `evaludate()`? Because it seems I can't call custom functions in MongoDB's `Find()`.

Comment: no you can't. mongodb linq doesn't function the same way as regular linq does. what you write in linq should be directly translatable to mongo query language. until you become proficient at mongo-linq, always try to look at what mongo query your linq was translated to. you can do that by doing `query.ToString()` in code or enabling profiling in the database with `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` and then seeing the last few queries with something like this `db.system.profile.find().skip(1).limit(6).sort( { ts : -1 } ).pretty()`

Comment: these two links will give you an idea of what's supported and what's not: [LINQ](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/crud/linq/) and [Expressions](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/reference/driver/expressions/)